# Update integer json object to become an array with one integer

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, psql

I'm currently working with psql and trying to update an embedded json object to change a value from an integer to an array with one value (this is due to a function changing elsewhere).

My table looks like this:

```
id | dashboard_settings
-----------------------
 1 | {"query": {"year_end": 2018, "year_start": 2015, "category": 4}}
```

However I want the category bit to change to [4], like below:

```
id | dashboard_settings
-----------------------
 1 | {"query": {"year_end": 2018, "year_start": 2015, "category": [4]}}
```

So far, I have this which allows me to access the category section but I can't figure out how to turn it to an array:

```
UPDATE table
SET dashboard_settings = jsonb_set(
    dashboard_settings::jsonb, 
    array['query, category'], 
    to_jsonb(dashboard_settings->'query' ->'category'));
```

I've tried to concatenate and cast as an array but had no success

Comment: Your array constructor should be `array['query', 'category']`.  The way you have written it, it's just a one element array.  You could also use `'{query, category}'`.

Answer (score 1):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d86c3bcdf32ebb57572ffaa7ead36423)

Instead of `to_jsonb()` you could use `jsonb_build_array()`:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET dashboard = s.out
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_set(
            dashboard, 
            '{query, category}', 
            jsonb_build_array(dashboard -> 'query' -> 'category')
        ) AS out
    FROM mytable
    WHERE id = 1;
) s
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you removed the accept and upvote? Is there anything wrong? Should something be changed?